# Schedule a job in SQL Server between two days

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs

How to schedule a job in SQL Server that starts on Wednesday afternoon and it should end on Thursday EOD and between this the SSIS package should execute for every one hour if any error occurs in first hour then it should automatically pick in next hour.

I need to schedule a job accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

When you need some scheduling logic that isn't available in a single SQL Agent schedule you can either

1. Create multiple schedules for a SQL Agent job.  That will work here, with one scheduling the job to run Wednesdays every hour in the afternoon, and one scheduling the job to run every hour on Thursdays.

or

2. Schedule the job to run every hour (or whatever) and insert a job step that has logic to abort the job when you don't want it to actually run.  You can use a TSQL job step configured to throw an error if the job doesn't need to run, and to quit the job reporting success on failure, eg

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'check if should run', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=1, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'

if (datepart(minute, getdate())<> 49)
begin
   throw 50002, ''job doesnt need to run'', 1
end

', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
```